# WordPress - “You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page” in production but not locally with AWS and Bedrock

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have an installation of WordPress setup using Bedrock(https://roots.io/bedrock/) hosted on Amazon Web Services' Elastic Beanstalk. I am getting the following error when I try logging in with my admin user:

> "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"

What's strange is that I only get this error in production. Locally everything works fine. The rest of the site also works fine in production.

I've been trying for quite a while, however none of the things I've tried seem to help. Below are some notes of what I've tried/noticed:

- Did not change table prefix for database
- Checked usermeta table - all the values are fine for wp_capabilities and wp_user_level
- Tried creating a 'force-upgrade.php' script.
- Can't access any admin pages by changing the URL (e.g wp-admin/themes.php)
- The issue arose after the switch the Bedrock
- Made sure the config files were identical in both environments

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's probably a file permission issue... are all the wordpress files owned by your server user?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for some more info https://discourse.roots.io/t/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page/3536/4

From the looks of it bedrock disables edits on production environments

This can be turned off by going to https://github.com/roots/bedrock/blob/master/config/environments/production.php#L14 and changing this line `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);` to `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);`